# create a unique id for select tag id when new row of data is added to a table

Tags: javascript, php, html

My title is pretty accurate to my problem but I think I may be barking up the wrong tree with the solutions I've been trying. I'm new to javascript and web development in general so forgive me for my lack of verbiage.

My program creates a new row of data when a part is selected from a drop-down menu. The rows populate with the data from an SQL table with information about the selected part such as: category, part_name, price etc. One of the td elements in the table is a drop-down to change the quantity that looks like this

```
    <td>
      <select data-id = <?php echo $row["part_id"];?> id = "qty_dropdown"> 
      <option value = '1'> 1 </option>  
      <option value = '2'> 2 </option> 
      <option value = '3'> 3</option> 
      <option value = '4'> 4 </option> 
      <option value = '5'> 5 </option> 
      <option value = '6'> 6 </option> 
      <option value = '7'> 7 </option> 
      <option value = '8'> 8 </option> 
      <option value = '9'> 9 </option> 
      <option value ='10'> 10</option> 
      </td> </select>
```

This sits inside a loop that I use to get the data from the SQL table. My problem is figuring out how to get the selected value of quantity when the id for each row is always "qty_dropdown". I think I need to add a unique identifier at the end of the id, "qty_dropdown" so when a new row is created, the id of the select drop-down becomes something like, "qty_dropdown1" and so on.Also, data-id is the part id of the selected row so there's a possibility I could use that as part of my unique As I said, I'm not sure if I'm barking up the wrong tree and I definitely don't have too much experience. There may be a much easier way to solve this problem. Hopefully I'm explaining my problem well enough to understand. Let me know if you need to see more of my code. Thank for the help!

Comment: Euh, not sure if I understand correctly, but the `.selected` property of the dropdown should give you the option that is currently selected.

Comment: I've tried this and it always just returns the first "qty_dropdown" value. So if I add two parts and change the quantity of the second part, nothing is effected. The first part the user adds to the table is the only quantity that can be recognized by the .selected property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your selects are created inside a loop you might want to use name instead of id. Ids are meant to be unique. If you use the name property you can access them on the client side in javascript space by using

```
var selectLists = document.getElementsByName("qty_dropdown");
var firstSelectList = selectLists[0];
```

Comment: yes! Awesome. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: actually. There seems to be a strange thing here. Wen I add a new part, it resets the quantity on all dropdown lists to 1 rather than keeping the selected value. Any idea why this is?

Comment: If the entire form is re-rendered you need to remember the previous values and set the selected flag for the selected option. Otherwise it will default to the first entry.

Comment: I tried a few different things and can't seem to come up with a good solution. Do you recommend a good way of getting this done? Thanks so much.